# Executing SQL queries using a file in special format

Tags: mysql, bash, awk

I am trying to write a script that reads lines from a file containing:

- a filename of an SQL script, and
- some SQL queries on the same line

and launches a query.

There is a `list.txt` file in the following format:

```
query.sql; set @var:='prod';
```

where `query.sql` is a file with SQL queries, e.g.:

```
select *
  from db
 where system=@var
```

I am trying to write a Bash script that executes the queries like this:

```
mysql -uroot -proot -e 
    "set @var:='prod'; 
     select *
       from db
      where system=@var;"
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
while read line;
    do app=$(echo $line  | awk '{for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) printf FS$i; print NL }';
    cat `echo $line | awk -F\; '{print $1}'`; echo ";");
    mysql -uroot -proot -e "`echo $app`"
done < list.txt
```

But I am having an SQL error, because the shell does not escape well the `*` character in the `query.sql`.

Debugging my code I obtain:

```
$echo $app
$set @var:='prod'; select a list.txt mysql query1.sql query.sql from db where system=@var ;
```

How can I adjust the code in order to have

```
$echo $app
$set @var:='prod'; select * from db where system=@var ;
```

?

**Further details**

There is a `loop` in the `awk` command, because the file `list.txt` may contain multiple queries, e.g.:

```
query.sql; set @var:='prod'; @a=asd; @b=zxc, @...=...;
```

Comment: My mistake, just edited the question (it was the real query I have on server)

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti, you want to execute the second SQL statement (after the first `;`), then the statements from the file specified before the first `;`, right?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov I'd like to execute my last row:  `set @var:='prod'; select * from db where system=@var ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to read the SQL files line by line. Assuming that there are no semicolons in the filenames, you can construct the query with the following AWK command:

```
awk -F\; '{
 for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
   if ($i != "") printf("%s;", $i);
 }
 printf("source %s;\n", $1)
}' list.txt | mysql -uroot -proot
```

The command uses `;` as a field separator. The `for` loop prints all fields starting from the second. The last `printf` function builds a query sourcing the SQL file.

**The Cause of the Error**

Your code fails to pass the correct SQL to the MySQL client because of this line:

```
mysql -uroot -proot -e "`echo $app`"
```

The shell interprets the special characters within the `$app` variable. In particular, the `*` character is expanded to "every file in the current directory". To prevent interpreting, use *weak [quoting](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)*, i.e. enclose the variable in double quotes: `"$app"`:

> When referencing a variable, it is generally advisable to enclose its name in double quotes. This prevents reinterpretation of all special characters within the quoted string -- except `$`, (backquote), and `\` (escape)...
>
> Keeping `$` as a special character within double quotes permits referencing a quoted variable (`"$variable"`), that is, replacing the variable with its value

Also, there is no need for subshell expression (the backticks and the `echo`), if you want to get the value of the variable:

```
mysql -uroot -proot -e "$app"
```

Comment: `awk -F\; '{for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {if ($i != "") printf("%s;", $i);} printf("source %s;\n", $2)}' list.txt `
gives me 
`set @var:='prod';source  set @var:='prod';`
and not the `set @var... ; query `

Comment: Yes you are right, I was modifying on my own and it works! Great

Comment: Just to understand better bash scripting (I am a newbie), do you know which was the problem in my code?

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti, I've added explanation of the issue in your code

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti, of course. For example, you can simply modify the AWK code accordingly (how? It depends on what you mean by "other commands".)

Comment: For example I'd like to use mv to a file. Where is the point in the AWK code to insert that?

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti, if you mean the _shell_ command `mv`, you can whether use AWK's `system()` function, or put the `mv` command outside the AWK code.